# Where is "Retarget Solution" in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: build, sdk, visual-studio-2022

I use Visual studio build one USB SDK, I got this message:

```
Error   MSB8020 The build tools for WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0') cannot be found. To build using the WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools, please install WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".   usbsamp (Sys\Driver\usbsamp)    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets
```

I try following this, use "Retarget Solution", but I can't find it in Project menu, is it for early visual studio? How I can fix it in Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio use different method set this, after I use Project->property->general->Platform toolset change to Visual Studio 2022, the error is fixed.